# Book on limit theorems for sums of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I'm currently studying for an advanced course of probability theory and I would want to find a book which explains clearly limit theorems for sums of random variables.

We used characteristic functions and derived three main cases (finite/infinite mean/variance) corresponding to Gaussian distribution, Levy stable distribution and another kind of distribution, which gives the Cauchy distribution as a particular case.

Then we studied sums as stochastic processes deriving the behavior of Wiener and Levy processes.

Can you recommend me some books on this topic?

Comment: B. V. Gnedenko and A. N. Kolmogorov, *Limit distributions for sums of independent random variables* - though you might have covered much if it. If you read Russian, you can easily find it online for download.

Comment: Another book that comes to mind is [*Sums of Independent Random Variables*](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=3642658091) by V. V. Petrov.

Comment: Yes, I found that book, thanks again :)